# How to design a rich editor for custom DSL on the web

Tags: javascript, algorithm, web-applications, user-interface

The problem I am trying to solve is an editor for a custom SQL-like DSL, which requires the user to input unique identifiers of properties instead of proper verbose titles. Think something like /obj/12075f8459499 instead of human-readable "firstName". The application in question is on the web and I want to provide the users with a nice editor that hides the implementation detail of objects having unique URIs.

I imagine it as a content editable DIV, where if you start typing a string that's also a start of a property title, you will be presented with a dropdown to confirm that this property is indeed what you have in mind. After you select an item, a placeholder will be inserted, which the application then knows how to serialize to my DSL syntax. You will also be able to select properties to insert into the editable area from a list in the sidebar.

My question is how to go about parsing the user input so that the resulting interface is reasonably responsive. Should I start with defining a grammar and then parse the input or should I start looking elsewhere? Seems like a problem like this has been solved in many applications, so I'm looking for pointers how this is typically implemented.

Note: I will also need to do syntax highlighting of the language, so some sort of grammar will probably have to be in place anyway.

Comment: Many of the packages for emacs which highlight language syntax have source code which you can read. That will give you some idea of how they approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with using [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) JavaScript editor. Its ability to mark a range of text and have it represented with some other HTML markup proved particularly useful. I employed this to show "friendly" object names in lieu of URIs.